# Handling Dates in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I am new to java GUI

I have a form for simple data input that saved to mySQL. Among the textboxes I have defined is dateOfBirth.

In mySQL, the dateOfBirth column is type DATE.

When I attempt to save my record, I get incompatible conversions. How Do I handle this? The Date fields are DOR and DOB.

I tried to define a format :

```
DateFormat df= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

and also changed redefined the var DOR or DOB as String:

```
String DOB = new String();
```

then when inserting into database, formatted the var like this:
df.format(DOB)

I still got the error: "Error: Cannot format given object as a Date". What to do?

```
String query = "INSERT INTO members (MemberID,FamilyName,BaptismName,DateOfRegistration,DateOfBirth,FatherName,MotherName,gender,MemberType,Address,Residence,City,CreatedBy)"
    +"VALUES('"+memberID+"','"+familyName+"','"+baptismName+"','"+DOR+"','"+DOB+"','"+fatherName+"','"+motherName+"','"+gender+"','"+memberType+"','"+address+"','"+residence+"','"+city+"','"+operator+"')";

    con.UpDate(query);
```

Comment: because DOB seems to be a string, not a date, its not doing anything with the format

Comment: Please read about PreparedStatements.  Don't escape query parameters yourself.  Why are you modeling a Date as a String?

Comment: MySQL date format is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Answer (score 1):

First of all i would not use that query for the insert. You should use a prepared statement. It's safer against sql injection.

```
PreparedStatement ps =
    connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO members (MemberID,FamilyName,BaptismName,DateOfRegistration,DateOfBirth,FatherName,MotherName,gender,MemberType,Address,Residence,City,CreatedBy) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
ps.setString(1, memberID); //or the correct type if not String
ps.setString(2, familyName);
ps.setString(3,baptismName);
DateFormat df= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); //this the the format in which the user enters the date in the textbox. they have to input a string like 12/31/2014
java.util.Date date=df.parse(DOB); //DateFormat class has a method called parse which returns a java.util.Date object
ps.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(date.getTime())); 
//PreparedStatement class method setDate takes 2 parameters
//first is the index of the parameter in the prepared statement, and the second
//is java.sql.Date object.
//use constructor of java.sql.Date which takes a long parameter to create this object
//java.util.Date getTime() method returns a long value representing the date object
//so basically you convert string DOB to java.Util.Date,
//then convert java.Util.Date object to java.sql.Date needed by prepared statement

...

ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thanks @MihaiC, How do I assign the value entered in the swing textbox (I assume it is a String by default) to DOB without getting the error?

Comment: @Sylvester if DOB is string just copy the value from the textbox DOB=textBox.getText(); You convert it to java.sql.Date before you set the value to the prepared statement. the string has to be entered in the same format you use to convert the date later so in this case user has to write 31/12/2014 or any date in that format

Comment: I am sorry, I can't understand the date formatting. I have worked with vb.net extensive, but I can't seem to understand the multiple lines of code I have to do, just to save a field into database. I am combing the net, but don't see, to find anything precise.

Comment: @Sylvester i added some comments, hope they are clear. You can read more about the classes and methods used from the javadocs. You will then understand what parameters they take and what objects or values they return.